# A .py utility file for neural network learing rate policies

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I've created a `.py` utility file, which specifies the learning rate policy for the neural network in **PyTorch**. The program in prior reads a `json` and creates a `dict`, called here is `cfg`.

So far, I have implemented 3 kinds of learning policies - `steps, exp, cos`, and for each of them I've created a separate class with the `__call__` method. I've done this to have this parameters set in the `LambdaLR` without further refering to `cfg` during the training.

In order to avoid branch of `if's` I've created a dict, which chooses one of the options, and in the function `create_scheduler` the instance of one of these classes is created, passed to the initializer of `LambdaLR` scheduler, and this scheduler is then returned.

```
class LR_Steps:
    def __init__(self, cfg):
        self.lr_base = cfg["OPTIM"]["BASE_LR"] 
        self.lr_mult = cfg["OPTIM"]["LR_MULT"] 
        self.steps   =  cfg["OPTIM"]["STEPS"]
        # the current index in the steps
        self.ind = 0
    
    def __call__(self, epoch):
        if epoch > self.steps[self.ind]:
            self.ind += 1
    
        return self.lr_base * (self.lr_mult ** self.ind)

class LR_Exp:
    def __init__(self, cfg):
        self.lr_base = cfg["OPTIM"]["BASE_LR"] 
        self.lr_mult = cfg["OPTIM"]["LR_MULT"] 
    
    def __call__(self, epoch):
        return self.lr_base * (self.lr_mult ** epoch)

class LR_Cos:
    def __init__(self, cfg):
        self.lr_base = cfg["OPTIM"]["BASE_LR"] 
        self.max_epoch = cfg["OPTIM"]["MAX_EPOCH"]
    
    def __call__(self, epoch):
        return 0.5 * self.lr_base * (1.0 + np.cos(np.pi * epoch / self.max_epoch))

lr_policy_dict = {
    "cos" : LR_Cos,
    "exp" : LR_Exp,
    "steps" : LR_Steps
}

def create_scheduler(optimizer, cfg):
    return optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_policy_dict[cfg["OPTIM"]["LR_POLICY"]](cfg))
```

My question is - if there a shorter or safer way to do this? I would also appreciate criticism, concerning the structure of code and functionality.

Comment: If each class takes one set of input and exposes one method I'd change them to functions. You don't need a class to map one input to output with any state. In this case it might make sense to create one class that accepts `config` and then wraps what you already have, exposing each of those as a method. You'd only need to set `self.lr_base` once then and each method would have access to it

Answer (score 7):

Overall I rather like this. It's a nice way to think about "configurable functions". Minor stuff:

- Due to order of operations, the parens around `self.lr_base * (self.lr_mult ** epoch)` are not needed
- It's worth splitting out a temporary variable for `cfg['OPTIM']`
- Consider annotating your member variables and method signatures with PEP484 type hints
- Decimals in `1.0` are not necessary due to float promotion
- Spaces before colons - `"cos" :` - are not PEP8-standard
- You've not shown unit tests. If you don't have them, write them.

If you're interested, a different (not necessarily better) way of thinking about these functions is that they can start as normal, non-class functions, where the first parameter(s) are the configuration needed; then call `partial()` to get a callable reference that you can then use as if it has only `epoch` as a parameter from the perspective of  `LambdaLR`.